# JavaScript loop from 00000 to 000256

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have files name `animation_00000.png` through to `animation_00256.png`. I thought I would be able to simple loop through and load them to screen like this,

```
var animation = $("<img id='animtation' />");
animation.prependTo(".stage");

for(var i = 00000; i < 00276; i++)
{
    animation.attr("src", "img/animations/cat/Catwalk_"+i+".png");
}
```

However this tries to load the image sources like this,

`Catwalk_0.png`

How can I make sure that all the zeroes are preserved in the count?

Comment: Uhmm... `"img/animations/cat/Catwalk_00"+i+".png");`?

Comment: That would just return `"img/animations/cat/Catwalk_001".png"` then `"img/animations/cat/Catwalk_002".png"` so on so forth, there always has to 5 numbers. So if the number is in the hundreds it would be 00100 and if not 00010 or 00001 etc

Comment: @Backboner - Doh, should have seen the trap :P

Comment: Be aware that `00276` is treated as octal, because it begins with `0`.

Comment: 00276 as octal is 190 in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
var num = "00000"+ i.toString();
var str = num.substr(num.length-5,5);
animation.attr("src", "img/animations/cat/Catwalk_"+ str +".png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Literals do not maintain their lexical representation when converted into strings. Or, in fact, after your script is parsed for execution. So those leading zeroes are gone. They also make your literals be interpreted as *octals* rather than *decimals*, which you certainly don't want here.

Instead, drop the leading zeroes, and use a string-padding function inside the loop body. There's no built-in such function, but it's fairly trivial to write one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function for padding numbers.  So, try something like this

```
function padding (number, maximum) 
{
  return number.length < maximum ? padding("0" + number, maximum) : number;
}
```

Then, change your loop to look like

```
for(var i = 0; i < 276; i++)
{
   padded = padding(i, 5);
   animation.attr("src", "img/animations/cat/Catwalk_"+padded+".png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iString = i.toString();

if(i < 10){
    iString = "0" + iString
}
if(i < 100){
    iString = "0" + iString
}
if(i < 1000){
    iString = "0" + iString
}
if(i < 10000){
    iString = "0" + iString
}
if(i < 100000){
    iString = "0" + iString
}
```

i'm not really sure about if this will work becuase i ame not an expert in JS. but this is how i solve this problem in most other code lang.